# Error: A value of type 'Uint8List Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Uint8List'. in .pub-cache folder

Tags: flutter

I changed sdk path this morning, and did:

```
rm -rf .packages        
flutter pub get    
flutter run
```

Then, the build fails with this error:

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/data_serializer-1.0.7/lib/src/platform_io.dart:14:35: Error: A value of type 'Uint8List Function()'
can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Uint8List'.
```

I tried `flutter pub cache repair` and `flutter clean` which was not effective.

I did not find similar issues on anywhere.
What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error is fixed in the latest version of the package, so you can change the version on your pubspec.yaml file to use the latest one (currently 1.1.0):

`pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  data_serializer: ^1.1.0
```

---

If you're not using the package directly, you can check which package that you depend on depends on `data_serializer` by seeing [this list](https://pub.dev/packages?q=dependency%3Adata_serializer), and you may need to upgrade that package. If it doesn't work, you might have to try [overriding dependency](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides).

`pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  data_serializer: ^1.1.0
```